# Recover page content when visiting back

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, d3.js, persistence

I am building a small web site, and on one of the pages there is a d3.js/highchart visualization demo. The visualization is interactive, and can be modified by the user.

When the user leave this page and enter another html page by following a link in this demo page, the content of the page is not saved, and when he comes back, he has to modify the chart again. My question: is there any way to cache this demo page so that as long as the user does not close the browser page, it can be recovered?

My simplest idea is to have each client page a unique ID. So that I will save the status of the page when the user leaves, and when he comes back I can cover its content based on this ID. Then the question is how to implement this ID for client pages.

Answer (score 2):

You can use History API here.

- When a user changes the state of the chart, the page URL is updated with all the parameters needed for rendering the chart (via history.pushState call).
- On page load you get the initial state (chart parameters) from the url and render the chart correspondingly.

A good thing with that approach is that you even can send such URL to another person, and they will see just the same customized chart.

Comment: Can you give us a link describing this API please ?

Comment: http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html .
An example site that uses this technique: http://visual.ly/vizbox/startup-universe/ . Search string specified by a user gets reflected in the URL, and then it is always accessible by this URL directly.

Comment: Cool, although not supported in IE :(

Comment: Supported natively in IE10+.
Use fallback to hashtag navigation in IE9.
You can use this library (or something similar) for that - https://github.com/browserstate/history.js

Answer (score 1):

I can think of many ways to do something like this.

If it was me, I would simply store the users chart settings in a cookie, so when they navigate back to the page, you can simply read the cookie for the settings and use them to re-display the chart.

If you want to persists this longer, then send the settings to the server to be stored in a DB. The server can return a unique ID which is then stored in a cookie, or simple use the session cookie to associated the chart settings with a session.

An alternative which doesn't use cookies is to add chart settings to the 'back' url when you navigate away. When the user clicks to go back, the url contains the information necessary to restore the chart states. However, this doesn't work if they click the browser back button.

Comment: Thanks. The idea of cookie is nice. But this won't work if the user opens two different tabs and each has a separate chart. I kind of want a tab-bounded-cookies...

Answer (score 1):

You could also try storing the page state locally using either `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` ([DOM Storage guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage))

Answer (score 1):

If you have two or more tabs I don't think there is a way to differentiate between then once they are closed. I would use Steve's idea about storing the ID in DB+cookie and when user come back to page I would provide them with a list of all their past modified charts based on cookie and DB query. Then they can choose which chart they want to reopen.